# hexo deploy finding .js and .css can't be loaded

Tags: hexo

I use hexo to build my blog,

- using `hexo s` to preview in `localhost:4000` is fine
  [image]
- using `hexo d` to deploy in a remote cloud storage service，and .js an .css resource can not be loaded
  [image]

---

- I checked F12, finding that resource is all 403
  [image]
- and finding that if I modify the address of a resource, it can be loaded, such as:

  - [sucess]http://calvinosblog.test.upcdn.net/fancybox%5Cjquery.fancybox.pack.js
  - [fail]  http://calvinosblog.test.upcdn.net/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js
- so I guess this `%5C` is **THE PROBLEM**
- **I would be appreciated that if anyone could help or guide me checking this issue**

---

here is my `_config.yml`, FYI

```
# Hexo Configuration
## Docs: https://hexo.io/docs/configuration.html
## Source: https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/

# Site
title: CalvinoShaw
subtitle: 苍穹煮雨
description: know your self
keywords:
author: Calvino Shaw
language: zh-cn
timezone: ''

# URL
## If your site is put in a subdirectory, set url as 'http://example.com/child' and root as '/child/'
url: http://example.com
root: /
permalink: /:year/:month/:day/:title/
permalink_defaults:
pretty_urls:
  trailing_index: true # Set to false to remove trailing 'index.html' from permalinks
  trailing_html: true # Set to false to remove trailing '.html' from permalinks

# Directory
source_dir: source
public_dir: public
tag_dir: tags
archive_dir: archives
category_dir: categories
code_dir: downloads/code
i18n_dir: :lang
skip_render:

# Writing
new_post_name: :title.md # File name of new posts
default_layout: post
titlecase: false # Transform title into titlecase
external_link:
  enable: true # Open external links in new tab
  field: site # Apply to the whole site
  exclude: ''
filename_case: 0
render_drafts: false
post_asset_folder: false
relative_link: false
future: true
highlight:
  enable: false
  #line_number: true
  #auto_detect: false
  #tab_replace: ''
  #wrap: true
  #hljs: false
prismjs:
  enable: false
  preprocess: true
  line_number: true
  tab_replace: ''

# Home page setting
# path: Root path for your blogs index page. (default = '')
# per_page: Posts displayed per page. (0 = disable pagination)
# order_by: Posts order. (Order by date descending by default)
index_generator:
  path: ''
  per_page: 10
  order_by: -date
  
  
# Generate archive page
archive_generator:
  per_page: 0


# Generate categories index page and each category page
category_generator:
  per_page: 10
  enable_index_page: true


# Generate tags index page and each tag page
tag_generator:
  per_page: 10
  enable_index_page: true
  

# Category & Tag
default_category: uncategorized
category_map:
tag_map:


# Generator atom feed for you website
feed:
  type: atom
  path: atom.xml
  limit: 20
  hub:
  content:
  content_limit: 140
  content_limit_delim: ' '

# For syntax highlighting
prism_plugin:
  mode: 'preprocess'
  theme: 'default'
  line_number: true



# Metadata elements
## https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta
meta_generator: true

# Date / Time format
## Hexo uses Moment.js to parse and display date
## You can customize the date format as defined in
## http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/
date_format: YYYY-MM-DD
time_format: HH:mm:ss
## updated_option supports 'mtime', 'date', 'empty'
updated_option: 'mtime'

# Pagination
## Set per_page to 0 to disable pagination
per_page: 10
pagination_dir: page

# Include / Exclude file(s)
## include:/exclude: options only apply to the 'source/' folder
include:
exclude:
ignore:

# Extensions
## Plugins: https://hexo.io/plugins/
## Themes: https://hexo.io/themes/
theme: landscape
## theme: typography


# Deployment
## Docs: https://hexo.io/docs/one-command-deployment
deploy:  
  type: upyun 
  bucket: calvinosblog
  operator: calvinoshaw
  password: xxxxx
  endpoint: v0.api.upyun.com
  secret: secret
  try_times: 5
  ignore_path_re:
    dir: null
    file: ".DS_Store$"
```

Comment: steps seem to be normal, `hexo clean` then `hexo g` then `hexo d`, but it just can not work